# Why there is no something like "static" in XMI?

Tags: xmi

Just as title said, there is no something like "static" in XMI, so how XMI express static properties or static operations in xmi files?

Answer (score -1):

XMI needs to support all languages' intersection, not union. IDL is one of the most important language XMI needs to support. However, IDL does not support "static", so for compatibility, XMI don't support "static" too.
But I still have a question: how we should do if we do need "static" in some scenes?